# How do I create a Drop down menu within a sidebar that offers the user's name and saves the answer to a variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, sidebar

I want to capture the user's name before they are able to work on a sheet.   I keep a log for when they are adding records to a sheet.  I have tried prompt box, dialog box.   I could never get them to work.  I been experimenting also with code created by ChatGPT.  In frustration I give up on Prompt and Dialog because I can not seem to control their size or location.  My users are already familiar with entering data into a sidebar, so I decided to use a sidebar for this task too.   I might want to ask them the time when they started working, and maybe their hourly rate. I can think of a few other things I would like to know when they start working.

I have opted to use a custom menu to start the process and open the sidebar. Here is my code, it does not work.  I have a Code.gs and a Page.html in my project.  Here is the code that does not work.

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var userNames = ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3'];

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate().setTitle('Select User');
  ui.showSidebar(html);
  sheet.hideSheet();

  function selectUserName(userName) {
    if (userNames.indexOf(userName) >= 0) {
      sheet.show();
      ui.showSidebar(false);
    } else {
      ui.alert('Invalid username. Please select one of the following usernames: ' +     userNames.join(', '));
      sheet.hideSheet();
    }
  }

  html.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
  html.userNames = userNames;
  html.selectUserName = selectUserName;
}

and here below is the companion HTML: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Select User</h2>
      <form>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <select id="username">
          <? for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?= userNames[i] ?>"><?= userNames[i] ?></option>
          <? } ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button type="button"  onclick="google.script.run.selectUserName(document.getElementById('username').value)">Submit</butt on>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone can help me get this working I would be so thankful.

I was expecting to see a side panel with a drop down menu inside the sidebar.

Comment: A lot of what you are doing is unclear to me.  There is no `Ui.showSideBar(false)`, `Spreadsheet.hideSheet()`.  You can not open a dialog or side bar from `onOpen`, you need to create a seperate function and install it say `onOpenSidebar()`.   There are many other things wrong with your code.  But first explain in more detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: thx for your comments and questions.  1st off, I know my way around gSheets and I have created some simple scripts a few years ago.  Now I want to take my ability to the next level.  This code was MOSTLY created by ChatGPT and I now understand that is persona-non-grata here.   So my entire post might need to be tossed.

Comment: I have been watching a lot of videos and help sites and countless hours asking ChatGPT to explain things about javascript.  And that has been helpful... but slow..  Now I am better able to describe what I want to accomplish.. and I think maybe I should kill this question and start over... Pretty sure that is what you folks want.  But I dont want to kill it without study it and thx the two folks that came to my rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of passing variables to the HTML template and getting the selection.  I start with and installed `onOpen` trigger `onOpenSideBar()`.  The side bar is displayed and I pick User 2 and press the submit button.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpenSideBar() {
  try {
    let userNames = ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3'];
    let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page');
    html.userNames = userNames;
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html.evaluate().setTitle('Select User'));
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function selectUserName(userName) {
  try {
    Logger.log(userName);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Select User</h2>
      <form>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <select id="username">
          <? for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?= userNames[i] ?>"><?= userNames[i] ?></option>
          <? } ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button type="button"  onclick="userNameOnClick()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      function userNameOnClick() {
        try {
          let name = document.getElementById('username').value;
          google.script.run.selectUserName(name);
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Execution log**

```
Cloud logs
Apr 4, 2023, 5:44:45 AM Info    User 2
```

Comment: This is helpful,  thx.  After a lot of research, and videos, I realize that I don’t wanna use a side bar. I want to use a dialog box with three radio buttons, and a submit button. I want to follow the rules here at stackoverflow.com and it seems that my question is inappropriate. But now I’m not sure how to rectify my error. Do I create a whole new question now that I know what I really want? And if so, do I delete this question?

Comment: If you are going to create a new question then I would suggest you delete this one so other user searching for a solution don't happen on this.